# Would it be possible to only use prepared statements when user registration and logging in

Tags: php, android

I am creating an android app that has a login page and registration page. After logging in the users will have to only press buttons to retrieve data from a database just like to display the data

Now my question is, Would it be possible to only use prepared statements when logging in or user registration to lessen the chance of SQL injection. While when retrieving data from pressing buttons will only use CRUD operations?

Comment: The answer is of course YES. There is nothing special/magical/difficult about prepared statements

Comment: "While when retrieving data from pressing buttons will only use CRUD operations" if data is coming in from a source you dont controll, it could be anything

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah I assumed so, I am kinda new to this so I was really wondering if it would be still safe if I only use CRUD operations, Since the user will not be entering anything but only pressing buttons

Comment: you still should sanitise the inputs

Comment: @nogad yes that is correct, I was just making sure haha So i really needed to ask from professionals haha